# Binary Search, Speed up using a nearby index

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

When doing multiple binary searches on a large set of data, Searched on nearby values could be used to reduce the size of the search.

For a simple example, lets say we're searching a range...

```
for k in range(n):
    i = binary_search(data, k)
    # operate on `i`
```

There are 2 obvious optimizations.

- Use the previous index as the first item in the binary search.
- Check the next item in the array matches (may be useful if the chance of a match is high).

However since `k` is ordered, it should be possible to pass the previous index into `binary_search` and (in most cases), reduce the number of times needed to bisect the range.

So it would look something like this:

```
i_prev = 0
for k in range(n):
    i = binary_search(data, k, index_near=i_prev)
    i_prev = i
    # operate on `i`
```

Is there a well known method for optimizing binary searches using the previously found index?

### Update

It seems a good method may be to use a galloping search with a binary-search, using the galloping search with the previous index to define the range, then call the regular binary-search function.
An advantage with this is its not complicating the binary-search code (which can remain a small loop, only doing simple operations).
Another advantage this method has is the galloping search can go both directions, so the index passed in can be more or less then the one thats being searched for.
I'd need to check, possible a galloping search on its own would be sufficient, just search until the items found instead of using to define the limits for binary-search.

Comment: Instead of searching in the interval [0,n] just search in [iprev,n] if you know that the successive k values are increasing.

Comment: You might try using galloping search instead of binary search here.

Comment: @Henry, Yep, infact I already tried quite a few different methods, but for the purpose of keeping the question concise, I thought it best not to go over all possible improvements.

Comment: @tmyklebu good point, was thinking maybe the range could be defined by galloping search, then call binary search too. Need to experiment a little.

Comment: Blog post - relevant to this topic: http://blog.teamleadnet.com/2014/06/beating-binary-search-algorithm.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how specifically the index is used.

The most obvious way of using it is selecting the middle elements based on some Gaussian looking distribution centered around the last element with a width determined by expected proximity.

This would be a form of [interpolation search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search), which normally uses linear interpolation to search in uniformly distributed data.

Methods like this are rarely used because they require a deep understanding of the expected data distribution. It's rarely worth the effort. At best, you save 25-30 comparisons searching a billion element array, while if either the heuristic is off or the data isn't as imagined, the algorithm may use millions of comparisons more.

Meanwhile, basic binary search is already implemented, debugged and ready to go, and guarantees you a result in log2(n) comparisons each and every time.

Comment: Is that 2 supposed to be an exponent or a base? If a base, then it's superfluous.